# Installing gmpy on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: python, module, 32bit-64bit, gmp

I cannot install gmpy (1 or 2) on OS X Mountain Lion without warnings. I tried `pip`, I tried compiling, I installed gcc 4.2.1 and tried to compile gmp with i386 arch (though my Mac is 64bit), none of them are working!

The thing is I can setup gmpy with Python 3+ without warnings but not with Python 2.7.

The verbose I get when I use:

`python setup.py install` for gmpy2 is:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'gmpy2' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DWITHMPFR=1 -DWITHMPC=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/gmpy2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/gmpy2.o
In file included from src/gmpy2.c:455:
src/mpz_pylong.c: In function ‘mpn_sizebits’:
src/mpz_pylong.c:55: warning: right shift count >= width of type
src/mpz_pylong.c:55: warning: right shift count >= width of type
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/gmpy2.o -lgmp -lmpfr -lmpc -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/gmpy2.so
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.dylib
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libmpc.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libmpc.dylib
running install_lib
copying build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/gmpy2.so -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gmpy2-2.0.0b4-py2.7.egg-info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, this error is caused because python is running as a 32-bit application but is trying to compile gmpy as 64-bit extension. See this issue report:

https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/issues/detail?id=11&can=1&q=Mac

Comment: I already went through that multiple times. Didn't solve the problem. Even when I run "arch -x86_64 python setup.py install"  I get the same warnings!

Comment: I see that the compiler arguments include both i386 and x86_64 as possible architectures. I this it should only list one. But I don't have access to a Mac to do any testing.

Comment: Well if you have time I would like to test whats on your mind.

Comment: Can you look at https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/issues/detail?id=69 ? Let's troubleshoot it there and I'll update my answer.