# Installing gmpy on OSX - mpc.h not found

Tags: python, clang, gmp, mpc

I have `brew install`ed `mpc`and `gmp` , but when I try to `pip install gmpy2` I get a compile error on the line

```
#include "mpc.h"
```

so for some reason `clang` is having trouble finding the `mpc` library. I'm not sure what I should do at this point.

Comment: Perhaps a [quick look through the archives here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138708/installing-gmpy-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion) would have been useful?

Comment: @hd1 I looked at that post but I didn't think it was the same error. Why do you think it is?

Comment: `"mpc.h"` seems strange - try `<mpc.h>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the maintainer for gmpy2. I don't have access to a Mac so I can't test OSX builds.

I assume you've also installed `mpfr` since it is a prerequisite of `mpc`. Where are the development files (i.e. `gmp.h`, `mpfr.h`, and `mpc.h`) located?

Instead of installing via pip, can you try installing from the command line? I use a command similar to:

python setup.py install --prefix=/opt/local --force

This command assumes that the `.h` files are located in /opt/local/include. You will need to adjust the prefix to suit your system.

Comment: Apparently the .h files don't exist anywhere on my system, so I'm installing from the command line through the tutorial on Google Code. Thanks!

Comment: @JakobWeisblat Please let me know if the installation instructions need clarification or can be improved.

Answer (score 49):

For OSX with homebrew users - I tried to do the usual dance with

```
brew install mpc
brew install mpfr
```

and then

```
python setup.py --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar
```

but got the error, that 'mpc.h' could not be found. True enough, there is no mpc.h file to be found. The solution is, to use

```
brew install libmpc
brew install mpfr
```

instead. After that gmpy2 was compiling and installing with no further problems.

Comment: I would like to point out one subtle misunderstanding mpc is "Command-line music player client for mpd" while **libmpc** is "C library for the arithmetic of high precision complex numbers". The second is what we want to install. call _brew info_ in case of hesitation.

Comment: This answer should be updated to just `brew install libmpc` because `mpfr` is a dependency of `libmpc` and `mpc` is not the library you are looking for.

Answer (score 17):

The short and sweet 2015 answer:

```
brew install mpfr
brew install libmpc
pip install gmpy2
```

Comment: Just tried this and it works on a clean OS X Mojave install. 10.14.5. Installed with pip3 install --user gmpy2 after the brew installation of mpfr and libmpc.

Answer (score 2):

As of the 06 March 2018, the only thing that worked for me was the following. (Install on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3, for python 3.5.4)

```
sudo port install libmpc
sudo port install gmp
sudo pip3 install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/opt/local/include/" --global-option="-L/opt/local/lib/" gmpy2
```

Note that `sudo port install libmpc` automatically installs `mpfr` as a dependency. `--global-option="-I/opt/local/include/"` basically tells the system that the header files for `gmp`, `mpc` and `mpfr` are in `/opt/local/include/` and `--global-option="-L/opt/local/lib/"` tells that the libraries to use are located in `/opt/local/lib/`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda or miniconda, install `mpc` and `mpfr` from conda-forge and then install `gmpy`

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge mpc mpfr
pip install gmpy2
```